# Why is $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(1+1/n)^s}{1+s/n}$ convergent for $s$ complex with $Re(s)>0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, infinite-product

Let $s$ be a complex number with $Re(s)>0$. I am trying to show that 
$$f(s) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1+1/n)^s}{1+s/n}$$  converges.

My approach was to look at
the sum $$\sum |1-f(s)|$$ converges, but I got nowhere with this. Could anyone either give a hint or provide a solution to why this infinite product is convergent?

*Edit* 
I corrected a typo which made the infinite product divergent.

Comment: I would say the opposite, i.e. that it is "divergent to zero", provided that $\text{Re}(s)>1$:
$$ \frac{1+1/n}{1+s/n}=\frac{n+1}{n+s}=\frac{1}{\frac{n+s}{n+1}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{s-1}{n+1}} \sim e^{-\frac{s-1}{n+1}}$$

Comment: I mistyped, I'll write a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the updated question:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \prod_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^s}{1+\frac{s}{n}}&=&\frac{(N+1)^s N!}{\prod_{n=1}^{N}(n+s)}\\[0.2cm]&=& \frac{\Gamma(s+1)\Gamma(N+1)}{\Gamma(N+s+1)}(N+1)^s\\[0.2cm]&=&N(N+1)^s B(s+1,N)\end{eqnarray*}$$
can be written as
$$\begin{eqnarray*} &&N(N+1)^s \int_{0}^{1}x^{s}(1-x)^{N+1}\,dx\stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{z}{N+1}}{=}\frac{N}{N+1}\int_{0}^{N+1} z^s\left(1-\frac{z}{N+1}\right)^{N+1}\,dz\\[0.2cm]&=&\frac{N}{N+1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}z^s\cdot \underbrace{\left(1-\frac{z}{N+1}\right)^{N+1}\mathbb{1}_{(0,N+1)}(z)}_{\to e^{-z}\text{ pointwise}}\,dz\end{eqnarray*} $$
hence by the dominated convergence theorem
$$ \lim_{N\to +\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^s}{1+\frac{s}{n}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}z^s e^{-z}\,dz = \color{red}{\Gamma(s+1)}.$$
You have just re-discovered Euler's product for the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: @Masacroso: $\prod_{n=1}^{N}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=N+1$ is a telescopic product.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(1+z)^s = 1+sz +O(z^2)$ as $z\to 0.$ (I believe the product converges for $s\notin \{-1,-2,\dots \}.$)

Comment: So let me see if I get this right, first, we have that:
$$ |1-\dfrac{(1+1/n)^s}{(1+s/n)}|  = |\dfrac{1+s/n-(1+1/n)^s}{1+s/n}|.$$ Now, for large $n,$ we have that this is less than or equal to $\dfrac{C}{n^2(1+s/n)} = \dfrac{C}{n^2+sn}$ for some constant $C$ (independent of $n$ for large values of $n$). Thus, for $N$ large enough $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty |1-\dfrac{(1+1/n)^s}{(1+s/n)}| < \sum_{n=N}^\infty \dfrac{C}{n^2+sn}.$$ Now, if $s \neq -1,-2, \ldots$ then the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} |1- \dfrac{(1+1/n)^s}{1+s/n}|$ is finite, so we have our result.

Comment: Great hint (if I was correct) thanks!

Comment: That looks right, although it might be easier to use the hint to see immediately the $n$th factor is

$$1 +\frac{O(1/n^2)}{1+s/n} = 1+ O(1/n^2).$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not convergent (unless $s=1$ of course).  The key facts are that $$\frac{1+1/n}{1+s/n} = 1 + (1-s)/n + O(1/n^2)$$
and the infinite product $\prod_{n} a(n)$ converges (to a nonzero number) iff $\sum_n (a(n)-1)$ converges.

Comment: Dear Robert:
I corrected a typo which made the integral divergent. Now I think the integral should be convergent, but once again, I can not see it. Sorry for not writing correctly in the first place!